# Convert a string to a positive or negative number

Tags: objective-c

I am new to ObjC. I've spent years working in Applescript and I've decided to move up. I am a hobbiest programmer.

I have the following code:

```
+(NSArray *) initArrayWithFileContents:(NSString *) theFilePath
{
    NSString *theContents = [(self) loadFile:theFilePath]; // returns the contents of a text file
    NSArray *theParagraphs = [(self) getParagraphs:theContents]; // returns the contents as an array of paragraphs

    NSMutableArray *teamData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array of team data
    NSMutableArray *leagueData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array of arrays

    NSNumberFormatter *numberStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    for (NSString *currentParagraph in theParagraphs)
    {
        NSArray *currentTeam = [(self) getcolumnarData:currentParagraph];
        for (NSString *currentItem in currentTeam)
        {
            NSNumber *currentStat = [numberStyle numberFromString:currentItem];
            if (currentStat != Nil) {
                [teamData addObject:currentStat];
            } else {
                [teamData addObject:currentItem];
            }
        }
        [leagueData addObject:teamData];
        [teamData removeAllObjects];
    }

    return leagueData;
}
```

This works fine for strings and for negative numbers, but a number preceded by a "+" sign is returned as a string. I figure I need to use a different number formatter style but I don't know what to use.

Thanks in advance,
Brad

Answer (score 2):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberStyle setPositiveFormat:@"'+'#"] ;
```

or

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberStyle setPositivePrefix:@"+"] ;
```

Comment: The first option works like a charm for a number beginning with a "+" sign, "-" sign or no sign, however it breaks converting a number (positive or negative) that has a thousands separator (","). I tried various combinations: (@" '+'#", @"'+'####", @"'+'#,###" for a few examples). I don't remember what all I tried. The second option didn't convert any of the number strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the + sign if one exists:

```
if ([currentItem hasPrefix:@"+"])
{
    currentItem = [currentItem substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [currentItem length] -1)];
}
```

Probably a better way, but this would work.

Comment: Much better - updated my answer, thanks.  I'm still somewhat new to objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was to create 2 NSNumberFormatters; 1 for decimals and 1 for decimals using the `setPositiveFormat:` method as described above. If the first formatter doesn't work, it'll flow on to the next formatter using the positive format.